# Could not find generator rspec:install. Rails4.0.5 ruby2.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, terminal, gemfile

I cant install rspec.

command:
rails generate rspec:install
↓
result:
Could not find generator rspec:install.

```
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.5'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

This is my Gemfile.
And, this tutorial is this one.
http://www.railstutorial.org/

Comment: have you done a `bundle install` yet?

Comment: Of course.I did bundle update and bundle install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replicated your gemfile and ran the command. It works for me just so long as the bundle installation finished correctly.

To make sure yours is installing correctly, you might try adding this line to your gemfile so that it can pull all the correct versions.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

Also, you may need to run your bundle install as the following if the postgres implementation gems give you trouble as they sometimes do. The tutorial you're working on uploads to heroku and doesn't require those gems on your development environment:

```
bundle install --without production
```

After everything has installed successfully, "rails generate rspec:install" should work.